# CSS Format Input (checked) Conditionally

Tags: html, css

I'm able to change the color of radio label text when the button is checked (eg. turning the text green), but I'd like to do so conditionally.  Ie. When option 1 is checked, I want the text to change to green, and when option 2 is checked I want the text to be red.

[JSFiddle][1]

HTML

```
<div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="option"><label>Red when checked</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option"><label>Green when checked</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Do you want both options to change together (i.e., both are green when option 1 is checked)? Or are both options a neutral color when unchecked and each one has a different color when checked (i.e., only option 1 is green when option 1 is checked)?

Comment: You need to use JS or jquery to do this. You can NOT achieve this by just doing CSS.

Comment: @BrandonGano - This is what I am going for: "both options a neutral color when unchecked and each one has a different color when checked (i.e., only option 1 is green when option 1 is checked)?"

Comment: See my answer below. The first solution should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want each item to have its own color when checked, you can use more specific selectors:

```
input[type=radio]:nth-child(1):checked {
  color: green;
}
input[type=radio]:nth-child(2):checked {
  color: red;
}
```

If you want both items to take on the same color, CSS alone can't do that [yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has). You'll need to use JavaScript to add a class to a parent container and set the styles based on that. Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="radio" data-color="green">
    <input type="radio" name="option"><label>Red when checked</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio" data-color="red">
    <input type="radio" name="option"><label>Green when checked</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  container.className = event.target.dataset.color;
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.green input[type=radio] {
  color: green;
}
.red input[type=radio] {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using JavaScript functions like
document.queryselectorAll()